# Benefits available to single-mom with low income, in Canada?

Tags: canada, benefits

I have been in Canada for 6 months. My husband and I have recently separated. I have a 4-year old son living with me. I am currently working but the income is very low. I earn about $800/month. Which benefits may I apply for and how?

Comment: Hi Jenny.  You may also want to do some research into benefits that might be available at the provincial or municipal/regional level (e.g. affordable housing programs, subsidized daycare.)

Answer (score 3):

[Government grants for single mothers in Canada.](http://www.ehow.com/list_6400456_government-grants-single-mothers-canada.html)

[Working Income Tax Benefit](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/wtb/menu-eng.html)

[Canada Child Tax Benefit](http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/cctb/menu-eng.html)

[Employment Insurance (EI) Compassionate Care Benefits](http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/ei/types/compassionate_care.shtml)

[Some extra help](http://www.singleparent.ca/)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you file your income tax report on time (also, getting it in early will mean it is processed sooner, which is an extra bonus) -- you can expect a GST/HST tax credit, a child tax credit, as well as some provincially-based tax credits. Any income tax that was deducted by your employer will also come back, as you fall within the 0% tax bracket.

Also, check out your local community centre - there may be some programs there that can help, like subsidized daycare (allowing you to work more or get training), assistance with your taxes and other financial paperwork, and general counselling.