# In Quebec, what kind of financial assistance might be available to an unemployed single mother with kids?

Tags: canada, children, quebec

My husband will be separating from me in a couple of months. I am unemployed and have two kids both under the age of 6. Is there a single mother's compensation? Especially in my situation where I am unemployed.

Answer (score 2):

1) Child support from your ex. Google "Federal Child Support Guidelines", and ask questions on www.ottawadivorce.com/forum

2) See here for information on tax benefits for parents http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/bnfts/

3) Low-income parents often qualify for subsidized (free or low-cost) daycare spots - though there can be a long wait-list for these.

4) See the Related Questions on this forum e.g. here [Benefits available to single-mom with low income, in Canada?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/5943/benefits-available-to-single-mom-with-low-income-in-canada?rq=1)